# How to use the properties of parent Include in child ThenInclude to further filter out the entries?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to write a query in linq lambda expression.
Let's say that the entity Customer belongs to another entity Organisation and will have a particular Staff assigned to it. But a Staff can belong to multiple organisations. For Example

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int AssignedOrganisationId { get; set; }
    public Organisation AssignedOrganisation { get; set; }

    public int AssignedStaffId { get; set; }
    public Staff AssignedStaff { get; set; }
}

public class Organisation
{
    public List<Staff> Staff { get; set; }
}

public class OrganisationStaff
{
     public int OrganisationId { get; set; }
     public Organisation Organisation { get; set; }

     public intStaffId { get; set; }
     public Staff Staff { get; set; }
     
     public int ExtraInformationId { get; set; } //information specific for that staff in that particular organisation
}

public class Staff
{
     public List<OrganisationStaff> OrganisationStaff { get; set; }

     public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

Now if we are querying Customer like

```
 await DbSet // Let's say DBSet is another enity like Appointment which is set between a customer and a staff
                .Include(c => c.Customer)
                .ThenInclude(a => a.AssignedStaff)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.OrganisationStaff.Where(o => o.OrganisationId == **c.** ....))
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Organisation)
                .Where(x => x.Id == customerId)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

Here how can I access the **AssignedOrganisationId** in the where condition? I don't want to use a constant. Is there a way to access the Customer properties? I know I can access AssignedStaff from the ThenInclude section but I can't access the Customer.

We can easily write the sql query like

```
SELECT * FROM public."Customer" C
INNER JOIN Staff S ON S.Id = C.AssignedStaffId 
INNER JOIN OrganisationStaff OS ON OS.StaffId = S.Id
INNER JOIN Organisation O ON O.Id = OS.OrganisationId 
WHERE C.Id = 10 and OS.OrganisationId  = C.AssignedOrganisationId;
```

I tried using a constant in that ThenInclude. It works if I do that.

Comment: What does it mean lets’s say? Which entity is the root of the query? It is important.

Comment: Your SQL query doesn't start with Appointment or whatever is in DBSet so it isn't the same.

Comment: Which dbset<T> you want start with in your linq?

Comment: The DBSet<T> is starting with Appointments. I want to fetch all the appointments for the customer along with the Staff who is assigned to that Appointment.